# Configurar Subdomínio da Loja Integrada

Tags: redirecionamento, dns, domínio, subdomínio

Tenho uma loja www.codigossagrados.com.br configurada na LOJA INTEGRADA e quero mudar para loja.codigossagrados.com.br para utilizar o primeiro domínio para um blog.

Alterei os registro de DNS A e CNAME de raiz e WWW do registro BR para o IP da hospedagem onde instalei o wordpress.

Criei uma entrada A  loja apontando para o IP da loja integrada (54.232.92.235);

Também criei um CNAME loja apontando para loja.codigossagrados.com.br.cdn.vtex.com

Eles explicam como fazer isso aqui:
https://ajuda.lojaintegrada.com.br/configuracoes/dominio/configurando-o-subdominio

E aqui (no caso de domínio próprio):
https://ajuda.lojaintegrada.com.br/configuracoes/dominio/configurando-dominio-proprio

Até agora, a loja está fora do ar e as modificações não aconteceram. Não consigo acessar nem a loja, nem o painel do wordpress.

Pode me ajudar?

Comment: [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIo5R.png

Comment: Amigo, antes de apontar um domínio à VTEX, é necessário que este domínio esteja cadastrado no módulo License Manager. É isso que conecta o endereço à loja.
http://help.vtex.com/pt/tutorial/configurando-dominios-no-license-manager/

Você chegou a fazer essa configuração antes de apontar o CNAME?